# keep getting error unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value(optional binding)

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, option-type

I have listed where my error is. On my app I am trying to retrieve data from Parse and display it in a custom PFTableViewCell with multiple objects. Everytime, a "null" value is returned for all labels, and that is what comes up as my labels...and I always get an error at the marked line: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)"

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import ParseUI
import Parse

class TableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {



    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as?TableViewCell
        cell?.gabText.text = object?.valueForKey("text") as? String ------> error
        cell?.gabText.numberOfLines = 0
        let score = object?.valueForKey("vote") as? Int
        cell?.voteCount.text = "\(score)"
        cell?.time.text = "\((indexPath.row + 1) * 3)m ago"
        let replycnt = object?.objectForKey("replies") as? Int
        cell?.gabReplies.text = "\(replycnt) replies"
        return cell!
    }



       }
```

Comment: Reduce the code you post to a minimum, see [Minimal Working Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example). This is way too much code for anyone to be bothered helping you

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why you're only getting `nil` for your object, but you can refactor it to do nothing when this happens:

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? TableViewCell
    if let object = object {
        cell?.gabText.text = object.valueForKey("text") as? String
        cell?.gabText.numberOfLines = 0
        let score = object.valueForKey("vote") as? Int
        cell?.voteCount.text = "\(score)"
        cell?.time.text = "\((indexPath.row + 1) * 3)m ago"
        let replycnt = object.objectForKey("replies") as? Int
        cell?.gabReplies.text = "\(replycnt) replies"
    }
    return cell!
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you get your object, but you can make sure a key exists before you get it's value, for instance:

```
cell?.gabText.text = object?.valueForKey("text") as? String
```

Can be inside of an if statement like this:

```
if object?.objectForKey("text") != nil {

}
```

That way you can ensure the text key exists before trying to get a value from it.

Comment: so what I can do is, state that first line outside of this function and then insert the second line into the function I posted, and post the key inside the if statement?

Comment: You can put the object?.value for key line inside of the if statement to make sure the key exists before you try to get it's value, you can put the if statement inside your cell for row at index path method - where you have the broken assignment now. - You should figure out why it's nil in the first place eventually if this isn't desired

Comment: I did that @thefredelement but instead of receiving a "null" text in my label, it gave me the text I originally named the label, which I planned to replace with the data from parse.

Comment: Sounds like you have a different question than fixing your error. I think you need to research how you interact with parse and why the key is nil in the first place.